# What is the pythonic way to merge a 2d list by one of its columns

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a large 2d list as `[[name, lower_limit, upper_limit], ...]`.
I want to merge the item list of the same `name`.

e.g., convert

`a = [['a1', 1, 10],['a2', -1, 20],['a1', 0, 8], ['a2', 0, 1]]`

to

`[['a1', 0, 10], ['a2', -1, 20]]`

The item lists of the same `name` are merged and their min lower limit and max upper limit are taken as the merged lower and upper limits, respectively.

Comment: You want to merge them? It seems like you are actually dropping repeated keys.

Comment: The most Pythonic way is the clearest and most readable one.

Comment: @Paul, not only unique, I also need to merge the data boundary.

Comment: @MarounMaroun do you mean the question is not pythonic enough (not clear and readable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way

```
a = [['a1', 1, 10],['a2', -1, 20],['a1', 0, 8], ['a2', 0, 1]]
b = [[key,min(el[1] for el in a if el[0] == key),max(el[2] for el in a if el[0] == key)] for key in set([el[0] for el in a])]
```

The outer list comprehension creates a set of the keys; the inner list comprehensions associate the keys with the max elements from the first and second bins using the built-in min/max methods

Comment: The output is `[['a1', 0, 10], ['a2', -1, 20], ['a1', 0, 10], ['a2', -1, 20]]`, seems need to unique the result.

Comment: @Dr.Lee Ya my first edit fixed that, just need to make a set of the keys

Comment: The question asked for Pythonic, I don't find this Pythonic at all.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It's inefficient, terrible to read, and it doesn't even produce the correct answer...

Comment: @JaredGoguen && Two-bit ... okay guys, hold the fire. It's got +2 and -2 votes. It's definitely an eye sore, and I won't remember what it was supposed to do tomorrow. I have a feeling that in a real world circumstance with numpy slicing this would be 1/10 of the length. For me (python 3.4) it does appear to produce the right result... I sometimes like the functional 1-liner approach for scripting something isntead of the 6 lines it took the other answer, apparantly OP agrees...

Comment: I'm not admonishing your answer, but it's an eye sore and that's un-Pythonic in my book. I don't think we should be entrusting the author with the definition of elegance. Not only that, for a scripting approach, this would take longer for me to write than the equivalent for loop.

Comment: @JaredGoguen fair enough. I appreciate the written feedback in addition to the (possible) downvote, thanks!

Comment: I agree with en_Knight and I like the all-in-one-line style of python (to me, that's also one type of pythonic). That's why I chose it accepted. I also agree with JaredGoguen that it's a bit of eyesore. And Two-Bit, the answer gives right results on my python 2.7. I don't know what python you use.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist  I haven't compared the efficiency of different answers. I accepted this answer but I finally chose other answer in my code. Because there are some `None` values in my data.

Answer (score 3):

```
L = [['a1', 1, 10],['a2', -1, 20],['a1', 0, 8], ['a2', 0, 1]]
d = {}

for name, low, high in L:
    if name not in d:
        d[name] = [low, high]
        continue
    if low<d[name][0]: d[name][0] = low
    if high>d[name][1]: d[name][1] = high
```

Comment: this looks pretty simple and clear to me.  Out of curiosity, any reason for not use the `min` or `max` built-ins in the last assignment

Comment: @GarrettR: I hadn't thought to use `min` and `max`. There's no reason to not use them

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the most Pythonic way is, but here is a method to do it using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
a = [['a1', 1, 10],['a2', -1, 20],['a1', 0, 8], ['a2', 0, 1]]

merged = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(a), key=itemgetter(0)):
    _, low_limits, high_limits = zip(*g)
    merged.append([k, min(low_limits), max(high_limits)])
```

This sorts and groups the outer list by the key (first element), then iterating over that just finds the minimum value from the list of low limits and the maximum value from the list of high limits.

**Edit**: Cleaned up per @JaredGoguen's suggestion below.

**Second Edit** Since OP seemed worried about performance, I'll say that it seems to me that if you have a huge amount of these keys such that performance will be a problem, you may want to look into using something like `numpy` or `pandas` for this task, but this groupby method is not something that scales.

I did a bit of profiling:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def merge_groupby(a):
    merged = []
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(a), key=itemgetter(0)):
        _, low_limits, high_limits = zip(*g)
        merged.append([k, min(low_limits), max(high_limits)])

    return merged

def merge_g4dget(a):
    d = {}
    for name, low, high in a:
        if name not in d:
            d[name] = [low, high]
            continue
        if low<d[name][0]: d[name][0] = low
        if high>d[name][1]: d[name][1] = high

def merge_pandas(a):
    df = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0)
    ndf = df.groupby(level=0).agg({1: np.min, 2:np.max})
    return [[k, v[1], v[2]] for k, v in ndf.iterrows()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Construct a large array of these things
    keys = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
    N = 1000000

    get_randint = lambda: np.random.randint(-50, 50)
    large_array = [[np.random.choice(keys), get_randint(), get_randint()]
                    for x in range(N)]
```

Then in an IPython shell:

```
In [1]: run -i groupby_demo.py
%load_ext line_profiler

In [2]: %load_ext line_profiler

In [3]: %lprun -f merge_groupby merge_groupby(large_array)
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 7.01214 s
File: groupby_demo.py
Function: merge_groupby at line 7

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           def merge_groupby(a):
     8         1            4      4.0      0.0      merged = []
     9         7      4328680 618382.9     61.7      for k, g in groupby(sorted(a), key=itemgetter(0)):
    10         6      2555118 425853.0     36.4          _, low_limits, high_limits = zip(*g)
    11         6       128342  21390.3      1.8          merged.append([k, min(low_limits), max(high_limits)])
    12                                           
    13         1            1      1.0      0.0      return merged

In [4]: %lprun -f merge_g4dget merge_g4dget(large_array)
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 2.84788 s
File: groupby_demo.py
Function: merge_g4dget at line 15

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    15                                           def merge_g4dget(a):
    16         1            5      5.0      0.0      d = {}
    17   1000001       579263      0.6     20.3      for name, low, high in a:
    18   1000000       668371      0.7     23.5          if name not in d:
    19         6           11      1.8      0.0              d[name] = [low, high]
    20         6            5      0.8      0.0              continue
    21    999994       828477      0.8     29.1          if low<d[name][0]: d[name][0] = low
    22    999994       771750      0.8     27.1          if high>d[name][1]: d[name][1] = high

In [5]: %lprun -f merge_pandas merge_pandas(large_array)
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.662813 s
File: groupby_demo.py
Function: merge_pandas at line 24

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    24                                           def merge_pandas(a):
    25         1       568868 568868.0     85.8      df = pd.DataFrame(a).set_index(0)
    26         1        92455  92455.0     13.9      ndf = df.groupby(level=0).agg({1: np.min, 2:np.max})
    27         1         1490   1490.0      0.2      return [[k, v[1], v[2]] for k, v in ndf.iterrows()]
```

From that it seems that using pandas would be fastest, and the lion's share of the work is actually done in the initial construction of the Pandas dataframe (which, if you are working with DataFrames or numpy arrays instead of lists of lists in the first place, is a sort of fixed cost).

Mind you, this is not consistent with the `%timeit` results for whatever reason:

```
In [6]: %timeit merge_pandas(large_array)
1 loops, best of 3: 619 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit merge_g4dget(large_array)
1 loops, best of 3: 396 ms per loop
```

Not sure why, but it seems there's some difference between the calls or whatever. Either way, if you have other tasks that are better performed on the data in `pandas` anyway, you're probably better off using that.

Comment: I recommend changing the second to last line to: `_, low_limits, high_limits = zip(*g)`

Comment: thanks for the profiling and suggestions. it's even a good tutorial of line_profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on cleaning up Paul's code (feel free to copy it and I'll delete this answer). This seems relatively readable to me:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a = [['a1', 1, 10], ['a2', -1, 20], ['a1', 0, 8], ['a2', 0, 1]]

merged = []
for key, groups in groupby(sorted(a), key=itemgetter(0)):
    _, lowers, uppers = zip(*groups)
    merged.append([key, min(lowers), max(uppers)])
```

However, since we know that we want each key to occur exactly once, I don't see any harm in using a dictionary.

```
merged = {}
for key, groups in groupby(sorted(a), key=itemgetter(0)):
    _, lowers, uppers = zip(*groups)
    merged[key] = (min(lowers), max(uppers))
```

Comment: I tested and `sort` is necessary. will it be inefficient if a is large?

Comment: maybe I can compare it with the conventional way as by inspectorG4dget.

Comment: @Dr.Lee Yeah, if you time then out, gadget's code far out performs any of the other options.

Comment: @Dr.Lee `sort` is necessary because `itertools.groupby()` only groups keys with consecutive matching keys. If you're worried about performance, you're almost certainly better off using a library like numpy or pandas that shifts this sort of thing to a C backend.